# Function with RxJS and combineLatest sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

If you call this function multiple times with the values of the observables obs1 and obs2 being the same each time, the returned array is not always the same.

```
getProductosUnicos(obs1: Observable<any>, obs2: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    return combineLatest([obs1, obs2])
    .pipe(
      map(([prod1, prod2]) => {
          return prod1.find((prod: any) => prod1.NombreProducto === prod2)
      }),
      toArray(),
      tap( a => console.log(a.length))
    )
}
```

What I'm trying to get are the objects from obs1 whose NombreProducto matches the strings coming from obs2.

As Liam ask me I add more code so that it is better understood:

```
  // component.ts
  
  getProductos() {
    this._gasolinerasService.getProductosUnicos(
      this._gasolinerasService.getProductos(),
      this._gasolinerasService.getProductosMunicipio(this.idMunicipio)
      ).subscribe( (data: any) => {
        this.productos = data
        if(!this.default) {
          if (this.idProducto == '') {
            this.idProducto = data[0].IDProducto;
            this.producto = data[0].NombreProducto;
        }
      }
      this.getGasolineras();
    })
  }


  // service.ts

  baseUrlGasolinerasMunicipio = "https://sedeaplicaciones.minetur.gob.es/ServiciosRESTCarburantes/PreciosCarburantes/EstacionesTerrestres/FiltroMunicipio/";
  baseUrlProductos = "https://sedeaplicaciones.minetur.gob.es/ServiciosRESTCarburantes/PreciosCarburantes/Listados/ProductosPetroliferos/";


  getProductos(): Observable<any> {
    return this._httpClient.get<Producto[]>(this.baseUrlProductos)
  }


  getProductosMunicipio(idMunicipio: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._httpClient.get<Gasolinera[]>(this.baseUrlGasolinerasMunicipio + idMunicipio).pipe(
      map((data: any) => data.ListaEESSPrecio.map((data: any) =>
        ({
          "Biodiésel": data["Precio Biodiesel"],
          "Bioetanol": data["Precio Bioetanol"],
          "Gas natural comprimido": data["Precio Gas Natural Comprimido"],
          "Gas natural licuado": data["Precio Gas Natural Licuado"],
          "Gases licuados del petróleo": data["Precio Gases licuados del petróleo"],
          "Gasóleo A habitual": data["Precio Gasoleo A"],
          "Gasóleo B": data["Precio Gasoleo B"],
          //"Gasóleo C": data["Precio Gasoleo C"],
          "Gasóleo Premium": data["Precio Gasoleo Premium"],
          "Gasolina 95 E10": data["Precio Gasolina 95 E10"],
          "Gasolina 95 E5": data["Precio Gasolina 95 E5"],
          "Gasolina 95 E5 Premium": data["Precio Gasolina 95 E5 Premium"],
          "Gasolina 98 E10": data["Precio Gasolina 98 E10"],
          "Gasolina 98 E5": data["Precio Gasolina 98 E5"],
        })
      )),
      concatMap(from),
      map(gasolinera => Object.keys(gasolinera).filter(k => gasolinera[k] !== '')),
      reduce((acc: string[], item: string[]) => acc.concat(item)),
      map(data => data.filter((item: string, index: number) => data.indexOf(item) === index)),
      map(data => data.sort((a: any, b: any) => b.localeCompare(a))),
      concatMap(from),
    );
  }



  getProductosUnicos(obs1: Observable<any>, obs2: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    return combineLatest([obs1, obs2])
    .pipe(
      map(([productos, prodGasolinera]) => {
          return productos.find((prod: any) => prod.NombreProducto === prodGasolinera)
        }),
        toArray(),
        tap( a => console.log("sdsf " + a.length))
      )
  }
```

Comment: What are the input observables? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I added more code. Thank you Liam.

Comment: TBH the code isn't very helpful, some kind of [marble diagram would be more helpful](https://rxjs.dev/guide/testing/marble-testing)

Comment: @OrsonWelles Do you get the same data each time you call GET on the two urls?

Comment: @Sharath Yes. You can test it in Postman.

Comment: https://sedeaplicaciones.minetur.gob.es/ServiciosRESTCarburantes/PreciosCarburantes/Listados/ProductosPetroliferos/

https://sedeaplicaciones.minetur.gob.es/ServiciosRESTCarburantes/PreciosCarburantes/EstacionesTerrestres/FiltroMunicipio/3398

Comment: @OrsonWelles, I did test it with Postman, wanted to know how it behaved on your end. Thanks for the info. I will check this further and update you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it. `concatMap(from)` emits at once so `combineLatest` not always works as expected. I resolved with `concatMap(a => from(a).pipe(delay(1)))`. Thank you all for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your component code like this and see if this helps. Basically, you store the observables in private variables and then pass that to the combine latest within the service.

```
export class MyComponent {
    ...
    idMunicipio = "";
    private productos$ = this.productoService.getProductos();
    private productosMunicipio$ = this.productoService.getProductosMunicipio(this.idMunicipio);
    
    ...
    
    // Use the observable variables in the getProductos() call 
    getProductos() {
        this._gasolinerasService.getProductosUnicos(this.productos$, this.productosMunicipio$)
            .subscribe( (data: any) => {
                this.productos = data
                if(!this.default) {
                    if (this.idProducto == '') {
                        this.idProducto = data[0].IDProducto;
                        this.producto = data[0].NombreProducto;
                    }
                }
          this.getGasolineras();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This way productosMunicipio$ is always passing the same value for this.idMunicipio. No matter if I change idMunicipio because the value of productosMunicipio$ is asigned just once. Every time I call getProductos() this.idMunicipio must be different.

Comment: If I move productosMunicipio$ = this.productoService.getProductosMunicipio(this.idMunicipio); to other function to update it, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you please send me the two idMunicipo that you used in your test below?

Comment: 3394 and 3398 for instance